# SuiteCRM - how fix issue while add dashlet to dashboard?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, suitecrm

the problem is that when I want do add dashlet on the dashboard of suite CRM, it shows me a blank window and into the browser's console show the error like this:

Google Chrome:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < at String.eval ()
>   at sugar_grp1.js?v=m7pFKeqRPAm5IJogTp-a-w:445 at Object.globalEval
>   (sugar_grp1.js?v=m7pFKeqRPAm5IJogTp-a-w:445) at Object.success (VM5134
>   MySugar.js?v=m7pFKeqRPAm5IJogTp-a-w:73) at
>   Object.handleTransactionResponse
>   (sugar_grp1_yui.js?v=m7pFKeqRPAm5IJogTp-a-w:55) at
>   sugar_grp1_yui.js?v=m7pFKeqRPAm5IJogTp-a-w:55

Mozilla Firefox:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

and into the file sugar_grp1.js , the mentioned line is this fragment code:

```
SUGAR.util = function () {
var additionalDetailsCache;
var additionalDetailsCalls;
var additionalDetailsRpcCall;
return{getAndRemove: function (el) {
        if (YAHOO && YAHOO.util && YAHOO.util.Dom)
            el = YAHOO.util.Dom.get(el);
        else if (typeof (el) == "string")
            el = document.getElementById(el);
        if (el && el.parentNode)
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        return el;
    }, paramsToUrl: function (params) {
        var parts = [];
        for (var i in params) {
            if (params.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                parts.push(encodeURIComponent(i) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[i]));
            }
        }
        return parts.join("&") + "&";
    }, globalEval: function (data) {
        var rnotwhite = /\S/;
        if (data && rnotwhite.test(data)) {
            (window.execScript || function (data) {
                window["eval"].call(window, data); //<======  THIS IS THE LINE MENTIONED IN THE WEB BROWSER'S CONSOLE

            })(data);
        }
```

the parameter called 'data' contains the HTML code...
and the HTML code starts so like this:

```
<div align="right" id="dashletSearch">
```

what's could be happening? how can I fix this?

Comment: Can't say anything without looking at screen and code.

Comment: disable error reporting, repair .htaccess and then try again